# If ReactJS state has a map property, changing the map value doesnot reflect the state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a component called Counters

```
export default class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counterMap: {}
  };
  noOfComponents = 5;

  componentWillMount() {
    var counterMap = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfComponents; i++) {
      var counter = {
        id: i + 1,
        value: i + 1,
        key: i + 1
      };
      counterMap.set(i + 1, counter);
    }
    this.setState({ counterMap });
  }

  handleDecrease = counterId => {
    // This is always Called from the inner child... Verified !
    const { counterMap } = this.state;
    const counter = counterMap.get(counterId);
    counter.value = counter.value - 1;
    counterMap.delete(counterId);
    counterMap.set(counterId, counter);
    this.setState({ counterMap: counterMap });
  };

  render() {
    const counterComps = [];
    this.state.counterMap.forEach(element => {
      const counter = (
        <Counter
          data={element}
          onDecrease={this.handleDecrease}
          onIncrease={this.handleIncrease}
        />
      );
      counterComps.push(counter);
    });
    return <div>{counterComps}</div>;
  }
}
```

My problem is

```
handleDecrease = counterId => {
  // This is always Called
  const { counterMap } = this.state;
  const counter = counterMap.get(counterId);
  counter.value = counter.value - 1;
  counterMap.delete(counterId);
  counterMap.set(counterId, counter);
  this.setState({ counterMap: counterMap });
}
```

This is not working in the UI.

Change in the counter value doesnot reflect in the UI.
My thinking is because the map itself has never changed, and only the values changed... and so the **React Thinks that the state has never changed !!!** .is it the right reason. I do not want to use array.
If I use arrays for counters, the code works absolutely fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an array? That seems more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: If you change the state using `setState`, the react will know that it's changed.

Comment: Because I this is an experiment. In real scenario, I want to load data huge data for server [ofcourse lazy loading] . Each Data will have a unique UUID from the Db and I want to create a Map of each UUID and the data itself. And so I will create components for each data and handle the interaction based on the id == UUID for each component..

Comment: @Amir : Thank you for your reply, I think the state for react is the memory location of the map object or memory of each key .... now each key is again an object ... 
So... no memory location has been changed .. I mean this is my understanding ... but again I am not sure ... Are you able to use maps in a state in your expereince ?

Comment: You shouldn't mutate the state or any of its fields. Your use of `setState` is wrong. You should use it in the form of `setState(previousState => {/*...*/})` and also you should create a whole new `counterMap` and replace it, don't update it. Because the state is immutable

Comment: @AkhilSoni yes you can use any thing you want

Comment: I might be way off, but I think in order to trigger a repaint, you need to mutate the state. So, in your case you could try to return new map by doing something like this `this.setState({ counterMap: new Map(counterMap) });`

Comment: @AkhilSoni Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should always update the state or any of its fields immutably:

```
handleDecrease = counterId => {
  // This is always Called
  this.setState(prevState => {
      const { oldCounterMap } = prevState;
      newCounterMap = new Map(oldCounterMap);
      const counter = oldCounterMap.get(counterId);
      newCounterMap.set(counterId, {...counter, value: counter.value - 1});
      return Object.assign({}, prevState, { counterMap: newCounterMap })
  });
}
```

**Explanation:**

First of all, if you need to calculate the new value of state based on old value, then you should use this signature of `setState`: `setState(previousState => {})` which pass the current state to you as argument.

Then in order to update the counter immutably, we first need to **clone** the counterMap:

```
newCounterMap = new Map(oldCounterMap);
```

You can see this is a clone, because `newCounterMap === oldCounterMap` is `false`.

Then we go on and update this map as we like:

```
newCounterMap.set(counterId, {...counter, value: counter.value - 1});
```

Notice the object spreading, that again causes a whole new object to be created based on `counter` (this is just a good practice, even if it's not critically necessary).

And finally we return a brand new object to replace our current state.

```
return Object.assign({}, prevState, { counterMap: newCounterMap })
```

Again, notice that I used object spreading here, so that we both return a new object and also keep the other values intact (not overwrite other entries of the `state`)